# All and My Views in Vf Page

Tags: visualforce, list-view, custom-view

I have an object Application. 
In vf page i want to have a drop down to have values as My application and All application.

Below that i have page block table which renders all application.

This page bock is rendered based on values in drop down.
Want to have same functionality as we have for standard view in salesforce.

I tried using Enhanced List.. but dosent serve my purpose.. I was giving the ids directly..

Comment: You can specify type of the object in type attribute too .Also have you tried apex:listviews as well?

Comment: Also how many views are there for that object ?

Comment: Want to implement this in this way....http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-i-get-a-selectlist-in-my-vf-page-for-a-custom-case-controller-to-work... but its not working...

Comment: @Mohith:- there are only 2 view All application and My application

Comment: simple apex list view should work for you!No need to do custom coding too

Comment: I dont want to use the ListView... Its giving me the same output as standard... ihave a pageblock table with 4 columns... have to render it based on value in drop down

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10778/discussion-between-testns-and-mohith-kumar)